# Milking order compatible with maximum number of observations

Tags: python, programming-challenge, sorting, graph

I'm using some old [USA Computing Olympiad](http://usaco.org) (USACO) problems to help teach me. This is the ["Milking order" problem](http://usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=838):

> Farmer John has \$N\$ cows (\$1≤N≤10^5\$), numbered \$1…N\$. He has made \$M\$ observations about his cows' social structure (\$1≤M≤50,000\$). Each observation is an ordered list of some of his cows, indicating that these cows should be milked in the same order in which they appear in this list.
>
> Farmer John's observations are prioritized, so his goal is to maximize the value of \$X\$ for which his milking order meets the conditions outlined in the first \$X\$ observations. If multiple milking orders satisfy these conditions, Farmer John would like to use the lexicographically smallest one.
>
> #### Sample input
>
> ```
> 4 3
> 3 1 2 3
> 2 4 2
> 3 3 4 1
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> ```
> 1 4 2 3
> ```
>
> #### Interpretation
>
> Farmer has four cows and would like to satisfy three partial ordering rules, in decreasing order of importance:
>
> 1. should milk cow 1 before cow 2 and cow 2 before cow 3 (the first observation)
> 2. should milk cow 4 before cow 2 (the second observation)
> 3. should milk cow 3 before cow 4 and cow 4 before cow 1 (the third observation).
>
> The first two observations can be satisfied simultaneously, but Farmer John cannot meet all of these criteria at once, as to do so would require that cow 1 come before cow 3 and cow 3 before cow 1. Therefore, the third rule should be ignored. This means there are two possible orderings: 1 4 2 3 and 4 1 2 3. Output the first, being lexicographically smaller.

This code works, but I don't really know any Python (or any other coding language). But that means I might be picking up some really bad practices just because I'm figuring out whatever I want on my own. Please let me know what you would change in the format of this, etc.

```
import glob
import copy

def mooSort(currentSort, fullGraphOUT, fullGraphIN, numCows): 
  """ Sorts the cows given the current list of conditions, described by fullGraphIN and fullGraphOUT. These are dictionaries dictionaries with vertex keys and and nodes either outgoing or incoming vertices""" 
  noIncoming = [] #keep a list of vertices with no incoming edges
  newSort = [] #the topologically sorted vertices
  newGraphIN = copy.deepcopy(fullGraphIN)
  newGraphOUT = copy.deepcopy(fullGraphOUT)

  for k in range(1,numCows+1):
    if not newGraphIN[k]:

      noIncoming.append(k) 
      del newGraphIN[k] #use this to keep track of if the graph has edges at the end

  while noIncoming: #take each element with no incoming edges and add it to our sort, remove it from the graph
    noIncoming.sort() #sorting so we can make it lexicographic as well
    m = noIncoming[0] 
    noIncoming.pop(0)
    newSort.append(m)


    for k in newGraphOUT[m]:
      newGraphIN[k].remove(m)
      if not newGraphIN[k]: #if there are no more incoming edges, we put it into noincoming
        noIncoming.append(k)
        del newGraphIN[k]
  if newGraphIN: #there's a cycle in the graph
   return False 
  else: #no cycles
   currentSort[:] = newSort #set the current sort to this one
   return True

#now do this in a binary search

inputs = glob.glob("*.in")

for input in inputs: 
    with open(input) as data:
       lines = data.readlines()
       #turn the lines into a list of list ints
       inputData=[list(map(int,line.split())) for line in lines]
       numCows = inputData[0][0]
       numConditions = inputData[0][1]
       inputData.pop(0)
       fullGraphOUT = {} #describe graph by outgoing neighbors
       fullGraphIN = {} #describe graph by incoming neighbors
       currentSort = [] #keep track of our current sorting
       for i in range(1,numCows+1): #initialize the graph to empty
         fullGraphOUT[i] = set()
         fullGraphIN[i] = set()
       for list in inputData:
         list.pop(0)
         for k in list: 
           for j in list[list.index(k)+1:]: 
             fullGraphOUT[k].add(j)
             fullGraphIN[j].add(k)
         if not mooSort(currentSort, fullGraphOUT, fullGraphIN, numCows): #once this gives false, we can no longer sort using all the conditions
          print(currentSort)
          break
```

Answer (score 18):

#### 1. Review

1. Python's [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) recommends 4 spaces for each level of indentation, and keeping lines to a maximum of 79 characters. It's not compulsory to follow this style, but it makes it easier for other Python programmers to read the code. For example, if you had stuck to 79 characters per line, we wouldn't have to scroll the code horizontally to read it here on Code Review. Also, with shorter lines it would have been easier for you to spot typos like "dictionaries dictionaries".
2. Although the problem description has to do with cows and milking, it should be clear that this is a very thin disguise and you're really just finding a topological order on a directed graph. So there is no need for the docstring to refer to "cows", and it's clearer to keep things abstract by naming the function something like `topological_order`.
3. It would be simpler if the function *returned* the topological order, instead of updating a list passed as a parameter. I guess that you implemented it this way because the function already returns `True` if the graph is acyclic and `False` otherwise. However, in Python it's easy to return multiple results from a function, by returning a *tuple*. So the code could become:

   ```
   if newGraphIN: # There's a cycle in the graph.
       return False, None
   else: # Graph is acyclic.
       return True, newSort
   ```

   and then the caller could use *tuple assignment* to give names to the two results:

   ```
   acyclic, order = topological_order(...)
   if acyclic:
       # Do something with order.
   else:
       # Handle cyclic case.
   ```
4. The code deletes vertices from the graph when there are no more incoming edges:

   ```
   del newGraphIN[k]
   ```

   The reason it does this is in order to "keep track of if the graph has edges at the end". That is, in order to be able to write:

   ```
   if newGraphIN: #there's a cycle in the graph
   ```

   But I think it would be simpler to leave the vertices in the graph as you go along, and to test at the end for any remaining edges:

   ```
   if any(newGraphIN.values()):
   ```

   This saves a couple of lines of code, and also enables a further simplification, described below.
5. Now that the code is no longer modifying `newGraphIN` during the construction of `noIncoming`, the argument `numCows` is not needed, because it is possible to deduce the vertices from the graph. So where the code has:

   ```
   for k in range(1,numCows+1):
     if not newGraphIN[k]:
       noIncoming.append(k)
   ```

   write instead:

   ```
   for v, incoming in newGraphIN.items():
       if not incoming:
           noIncoming.append(v)
   ```

   or more simply, using a *list comprehension*:

   ```
   noIncoming = [v for v, incoming in newGraphIN.items() if not incoming]
   ```
6. At each step the code needs to extract the smallest vertex in the `noIncoming` list (in order to get the lexicographically smallest topological sort). In order to do so, it sorts the whole `noIncoming` list. But this is inefficient: if there are \$n\$ items in the list it takes \$O(n\log n)\$ to sort them, and another \$O(n)\$ to pop the smallest item.

   This can be improved to \$O(\log n)\$ per item if `noIncoming` is represented as a [*heap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)). A heap is a data structure that is specialized for efficient repeated extraction of the minimum item, which is what is needed here. Python has a [`heapq`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module implementing this data structure and the associated algorithms. In this case we start by turning `noIncoming` into a heap by calling [`heapq.heapify`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify):

   ```
   heapify(noIncoming)
   ```

   then to extract the smallest vertex from the heap, we call [`heapq.heappop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappop):

   ```
   m = heappop(noIncoming)
   ```

   and to add a new vertex to the heap, we call [`heapq.heappush`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.heappush):

   ```
   heappush(noIncoming, k)
   ```
7. Since the code never modifies `newGraphOUT`, there is no need to make a copy.
8. It is not necessary for the function to take both `fullGraphOUT` (the directed graph) and `fullGraphIN` (the same graph with all edges reversed), since the latter can easily be computed from the former, taking no longer than it would take to make the copy.
9. I think the names could be improved: I would write `graph` instead of `fullGraphOUT`, `reversed_graph` instead of `newGraphIN`, `order` instead of `newSort`, `v` and `w` for vertices instead of `m` and `k`, and `sources` instead of `noIncoming` (because [*sources* and *sinks*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph#Indegree_and_outdegree) are the terms from graph theory for vertices with no incoming and outgoing edges respectively).

#### 2. Revised code

```
from heapq import heapify, heappop, heappush

def topological_order(graph): 
    """Return the lexicographically smallest topological order of the
    vertices in graph (if possible).

    graph must be represented as a mapping from vertex to an iterable
    of its neighbours.

    Returns:
    acyclic -- True, if graph is acyclic, otherwise False.
    order -- The topological order, if graph is acyclic, otherwise None.

    """
    # Copy of graph with all edges reversed.
    reversed_graph = {v:set() for v in graph}
    for v, outgoing in graph.items():
        for w in outgoing:
            reversed_graph[w].add(v)

    # Topological order.
    order = []

    # Heap of sources (vertices with no incoming edges).
    sources = [v for v, incoming in reversed_graph.items() if not incoming]
    heapify(sources)

    while sources:
        v = heappop(sources)
        order.append(v)
        for w in graph[v]:
            incoming = reversed_graph[w]
            incoming.remove(v)
            if not incoming:
                heappush(sources, w)

    if any(reversed_graph.values()):
        # Some edges remain, hence there's a cycle in the graph.
        return False, None
    else:
        return True, order
```

#### 3. Analysis

The milking order problem is a disguise for a problem known as **incremental topological sorting** or **online cycle detection**. In this problem you have a directed graph and you are given edges one at a time (or in batches as in the USACO problem) to add to the graph, and after adding any edge (or batch of edges) you need to be able to determine if the graph contains a cycle, or to output a topological order on the vertices of the graph.

When the code in the post is given new edges, it updates the directed graph with those edges, and then calls `mooSort` (or `topological_order` in the revised code), which runs a modification of [Kahn's topological sorting algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn's_algorithm) on the graph. Kahn's algorithm normally takes time proportional to the number of vertices \$N\$ plus the number of edges \$E\$, that is, \$O(N + E)\$, but because we need the lexicographically smallest topological order, we incur a further penalty for finding the smallest vertex at each step, making it \$O(N^2\log N + E)\$ (in the original code) or \$O(N\log N + E)\$ (in the revised code).

The topological order gets re-computed after every batch of edges has been added to the graph, so `topological_order` gets called \$O(M)\$ times, making the overall runtime \$O(MN\log N + ME)\$ (in the revised code). The number of edges is \$O(\min(N^2, MN))\$, as there can be at most one edge between every pair of vertices, and at most \$N\$ edges are added in each batch, so the overall runtime is \$O(MN(\log N + \min(N, M)))\$.

We would like to do better than this, but that's not a simple matter, because the incremental topological sorting problem is still an area of active research, and the best known algorithms are complicated. Take a look at this paper for a survey of the state of the art as of 2008:

- Bernhard Haeupler, Siddhartha Sen, Robert E. Tarjan (2008). "[Incremental Topological Ordering and Strong Component Maintenance](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0792)".     arXiv:0803.0792 [cs.DS].

Comment: Thank you Gareth! I learned a lot from this. I really liked implementing the heap there and learning about it. There were also several tricks and standard of Python I learned from this, my code is definitely better here and hopefully the next puzzle I work out will have look better than this one from the start!

Answer (score 9):

> ```
> def mooSort(currentSort, fullGraphOUT, fullGraphIN, numCows): 
>   """ Sorts the cows given the current list of conditions, described by fullGraphIN and fullGraphOUT. These are dictionaries dictionaries with vertex keys and and nodes either outgoing or incoming vertices"""
> ```

You can split a docstring over multiple lines to make it easier to read.

It's not immediately obvious what is meant by "*nodes*".

---

> ```
>   noIncoming = [] #keep a list of vertices with no incoming edges
>   newSort = [] #the topologically sorted vertices
>   newGraphIN = copy.deepcopy(fullGraphIN)
>   newGraphOUT = copy.deepcopy(fullGraphOUT)
> ```

Python style is to [use lower case words with underscores for variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id45).

I don't see the benefit of creating new names for the defensive copies. IMO it's safer to reuse the name of the parameter, because that way you can't accidentally modify the original dictionary.

The names `xIN` and `xOUT` sound like in- and out-parameters. The comment explains their meaning, but I think there are more transparent names, such as `predecessors` and `successors`.

---

> ```
>   for k in range(1,numCows+1):
>     if not newGraphIN[k]:
>
>       noIncoming.append(k) 
>       del newGraphIN[k] #use this to keep track of if the graph has edges at the end
> ```

It's unnecessary to delete from the graph to track whether it has edges: you can easily test that with `len(newSort) == numCows`.

In fact, I can't see that `newGraphIN` is necessary at all. The only thing you care about it *how many* predecessors a vertex still has.

---

> ```
>   while noIncoming: #take each element with no incoming edges and add it to our sort, remove it from the graph
>     noIncoming.sort() #sorting so we can make it lexicographic as well
> ```

I won't repeat Gareth's point about using a heap.

---

> ```
>    currentSort[:] = newSort #set the current sort to this one
> ```

This was unexpected. The docstring said nothing about `currentSort`, and I wasn't expecting it to be a form of output. IMO it would be sufficient to return `newSort` if it's complete or `None` otherwise.

---

> ```
> #now do this in a binary search
> ```

The code which follows looks like a linear search, not a binary one. Is this comment a statement of intention which was forgotten when the code gave the right answer?

---

> ```
>        lines = data.readlines()
>        #turn the lines into a list of list ints
>        inputData=[list(map(int,line.split())) for line in lines]
>        numCows = inputData[0][0]
>        numConditions = inputData[0][1]
>        inputData.pop(0)
>        fullGraphOUT = {} #describe graph by outgoing neighbors
>        fullGraphIN = {} #describe graph by incoming neighbors
>        currentSort = [] #keep track of our current sorting
>        for i in range(1,numCows+1): #initialize the graph to empty
>          fullGraphOUT[i] = set()
>          fullGraphIN[i] = set()
>        for list in inputData:
>          list.pop(0)
>          for k in list: 
>            for j in list[list.index(k)+1:]: 
>              fullGraphOUT[k].add(j)
>              fullGraphIN[j].add(k)
>          if not mooSort(currentSort, fullGraphOUT, fullGraphIN, numCows): #once this gives false, we can no longer sort using all the conditions
>           print(currentSort)
>           break
> ```

This looks like a bit much for a single loop body. Why not split the input processing into a function?

---

> ```
>          for k in list: 
>            for j in list[list.index(k)+1:]: 
>              fullGraphOUT[k].add(j)
>              fullGraphIN[j].add(k)
> ```

This is overkill. It suffices to add each edge once: you don't need to compute the transitive closure.

Comment: Thank you Peter! I learned a lot from this, especially about more sensible ways to apply my ideas in Python. I've applied everything you talked about here (my code looks much nicer now!), including turning stripping the inputs into a function. So now I have two functions (one that sorts and one that process inputs), as well as the loop body. P.S. you were right that the binary sort was a remnant of my initial idea that didn't really pan out after writing. This is definitely a linear sort.